# Why it just gives me nothing?

Tags: python

I wanted to make a list in put in it some variables, but when I start this code it's just closing. I am new in python (and coding at all) so what's wrong with code?

```
sh = 8
sm = 15
length = 45


sme = sm + length
sme *= 7
num = list(range(sm,sme,length))
ns = 1
n1 = 2 * ns
n2 = 5 * ns
n3 = 8 * ns 
for i in num:
     num.insert(n1, n1 + 5)
     num.insert(n2, n2 + 10)
     num.insert(n3, n3 + 15)
     if ns == 1:
         ns += 2
     elif ns%3 == 0: 
         ns += 3
print(num)
```

Comment: The loop never ends, because you keep increasing the length of `num` while you're looping over it. So you never reach the end.

Comment: You keep adding things to the list you're iterating over. It's like eating soup under rain.

Comment: If you just want to loop for the original length, you can do `for _ in range(len(num)):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your loop is never-ending since you keep increasing the num's length.
So, just loop till the definite length of `num`.

```
sh = 8
sm = 15
length = 45


sme = sm + length
sme *= 7
num = list(range(sm,sme,length))
ns = 1
n1 = 2 * ns
n2 = 5 * ns
n3 = 8 * ns 
for _ in range(len(num)): # Here you are providing a definite(or original length to `for loop`)
     num.insert(n1, n1 + 5)
     num.insert(n2, n2 + 10)
     num.insert(n3, n3 + 15)
     if ns == 1:
         ns += 2
     elif ns%3 == 0: 
         ns += 3
print(num)
```